# Unable to launch SOS.dll using VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to launch the `SOS.dll` from **Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate**. I get the below errors.

> Error during command: IDebugClient asked for unimplemented interface 
>   Error during command: Exception c0000005 occurred at 1BC4EF9E

I have also enabled the unmanaged debugging for the project. Not sure what I am missing. 
I tried to launch the sos.dll using following commands

```
.load sos
.load sos.dll
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll
```

Not sure what I am missing.

I am able to `load SOS.dll` when used with **VS 2008**.
Any advise is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Yogendra

Comment: You need to get your machine stable again.  This invariably includes reinstalling VS.

Comment: Do you have VS 11 Beta installed? I'm having the same problem and my guess is an update to the .Net 4 framework caused this.

Comment: I have the VS 11 Beta installed. My guess is that might be the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SOS.dll does not work in VS2010 if you have upgraded your CLR to .NET 4.5.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742882/after-installing-visual-studio-11-beta-load-sos-fails-in-visual-studio-2010