# VS2010 loaded SOS.dll successfully but other commands can't be used on my 64bit OS

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, sos

As you see,I use VS2010 Professional to load sos.dll ，but other commands can't be used and continues throw an Exception,like this:

> .load sos.dll extension
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll loaded
>
> !clrstack PDB symbol for clr.dll not loaded OS Thread Id: 0x6d4 (1748)
>   Child SP IP       Call Site 0028f2b8 00370094
>   ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(System.String[])**Error during
>   command: IDebugClient asked for unimplemented interface**
>
> 0028f528 699e21bb [GCFrame: 0028f528]

My pc runs on 64Bit Win7 ,can that be the problerm?

Can anyone help me?Really appreciated!

Comment: If you believe this is a 64-bit related issue, you may try explicitly loading the 64-bit sos.dll `.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SOS.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled "Unmanaged code debugging"?

See this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsdebug/thread/04e1f64a-aea6-4516-b75d-e4cb1ac0f872

Did you upgrade to .NET 4.5?  It appears that can cause issues.

[Unable to launch SOS.dll using VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150810/unable-to-launch-sos-dll-using-vs-2010)

I know in WinDBG you can issue this command:

```
.loadby sos clr
```

This causes it to load the sos.dll that is in the same directory as the clr.

Comment: Thank you.No,I didn't. And use ".loadby sos clr " command Windbg throw an Exception:Unable to find module 'clr'... Then i use the absolute path ,it gives me any response

Comment: What does ".loadby sos mscorwks" give you?  What version of the framework are you targeting?

Comment: >Unable to find module 'mscorwks'<br/> .Net 4.0 Now I'm debugging in my 32bit VM,sos gives me that:PARAMETERS:
        args (0x0012f3d8) = 0x00c8c450
    LOCALS:
        0x0012f3d4 = 0x00000000,but in the main function ,there's a console.writeline() statement,as if it didn't execute... I really should say:you're such a nice guy!

Comment: If ".loadby sos clr" says it can't find CLR it may be too early in the process, and the CLR isn't loaded yet.  Try running this command before anything "sxe ld:mscorlib", that should cause it to break when the CLR is loaded, then do the ".loadby sos clr" command, see what happens.

Comment: Thanks,really appreciated!But I really can't follow you... I'm a rookie,I just want to use SOS.dll now.Windbg is a bit difficulty for me now... And the reason of the error, i don't konw either.But the reason why the local is 0x00000000 is I didn't set any **breakpoint** and execute directly which i didn't know before.So sorry for **wasting your valuable time**!